# How can I access a post's feature image outside the loop?

Tags: loop, post-thumbnails

I want to update my `<meta property="og:image" content="http://amemoirproject.com/facebook/og-image.png"/>` tag in the head with the current post's feature image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

On a single post page the `$post` variable should work for you. It is set well before the page header prints. You will need [`get_post_thumbnail_id`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) and [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

```
 if (is_single()) {
    $thumbid = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
    $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbid);
    $src = $imgsrc[0];
    //   wp_die(var_dump($src)); // debugging/confirmation
}
```

I don't know how your theme is written or how that meta tag is inserted so I can't say exactly how to insert the image source into that tag, but the above will get you the URL.

`$src` will be `NULL` if there is no featured image so use `isset` or `empty` to check the variable before using it.